# error handling in R: access known object within function at time of function error

Tags: r, error-handling

here's a example function, let's say i'm unable able to edit it.

```
myfun <- function(){ x <- 1 ; stop( "error here" ) }
```

when the `stop()` occurs, how would i access the object `x` to see what it was?

not sure if i should use something like this, or if i need something related to `dump.frames`, or if this is simply not possible without changing `myfun()`

```
withCallingHandlers( myfun() , error = function(e){ print( e ) } )
```

i am looking for something similar to this behavior, but need to do it without `myfun()`

```
myfun <- function(){ on.exit( print( x ) ) ; x <- 1 ; stop( "error here" ) }
myfun()
```

for my use-case, i am unable to change `myfun()` because there are about fifty functions, but i want to know a consistently-named object within each of them at time of error

thanks!

Comment: Quick and dirty way is to make `x` global: `x <<- 1`. But your question proposes much more elegant way to do that.

Comment: @Heikki hi, how would this be done without editing `myfun()`?  but yeah, i think i'd prefer to avoid creating a global variable..

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cannot edit the function? Not clear on what the context is here. If I am doing development work, I typically use `devtools` to install & load a local version of the library, where I am able to insert various `print` statements to facilitate understanding these aspects.

Comment: hi, just want to know if there's a way to avoid adding the same block of `on.exit` code in fifty places..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with `trace`. I use also `purr::walk` as it is silent but you can use `sapply` instead for the same effect.

First let's define 3 functions, as you have 50 of them:

```
myfun1 <- function(){ x <- 1 ; stop( "error here" ) }
myfun2 <- function(){ x <- 2 ; banana(2) }
myfun3 <- function(){ x <- 3 ; x <- "potatoe" + x }

myfun1() # Error in myfun1() : error here
myfun2() # Error in myfun2() : could not find function "banana"
myfun3() # Error in "potatoe" + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Then put their names in a vector, and just apply this code, that will print `x` whenever exiting the function :

```
funs <- c("myfun1","myfun2","myfun3")
purrr::walk(funs,trace,exit = quote(print( x )))

myfun1() 
# Error in myfun1() : error here
# Tracing myfun1() on exit 
# [1] 1

myfun2()
# Error in myfun2() : could not find function "banana"
# Tracing myfun2() on exit 
# [1] 2

myfun3()
# Error in "potatoe" + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
# Tracing myfun3() on exit 
# [1] 3
```

And then get back to normal:

```
purrr::walk(funs,untrace)
```

**EDIT**

With method above, `x` will be printed even when there's no error

```
myfun4 <- function(){ x <- 4 ; TRUE }
trace(myfun4, exit = quote(print( x )))
myfun4()
Tracing myfun4() on exit 
[1] 4
[1] TRUE
```

To print `x` only on error, you can use following code, by the same token I've set `print` parameter to `FALSE` for lighter display and made it clearer than the printed value in case of error was x :

```
untrace(myfun4)
funs <- c("myfun1","myfun2","myfun3","myfun4") 
purrr::walk(funs,trace, print=FALSE,exit=quote(
  if(exists(".Traceback") && .Traceback[[length(.Traceback)]] == sys.calls()[[1]]){
    message("x at time of error:")
    print(x)}))

myfun3()
# Error in "potatoe" + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
# x at time of error:
# [1] 3

myfun4()
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: thank you for this.  if the function does not exit with an error, is there a way to avoid printing?  so `myfun4 <- function(){ x <- 4 ; TRUE } ; trace(myfun4, exit = quote(print( x ))) ; myfun4()` prints `4` but i don't want it to

Comment: See updated answer, I also changed a couple other things to make it neater,

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1:**

You could, of course, step through the functions using `browser()`, but this may be too time consuming for what you want.

**Option 2**

Although you say that the reason you are unable to change myfun() is "because there are about fifty functions", this does not present an insurmountable barrier.  One of the powerful things about R is that it can edit its own functions. So we can add an `on.exit` call to the function like this:

```
body(myfun) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), expression(on.exit(print(x))), body(myfun)))
```

We can wrap this in a handy function which does not change the original function like this:

```
print.on.exit = function(f, ...){
  body(f) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), expression(on.exit(print(x))), body(f)))
  f(...)
}

print.on.exit(myfun)
```

Comment: hi, thanks..sorry for being unclear.  your answers 2 and 3 assume that a `stop()` is always the cause of the error.  my code downloads different files from websites that change a lot, so the errors within the functions can't be narrowed to a single type of error..  answer 1 isn't feasible because i'm trying to print useful information for me (the R package maintainer) to help debug on a user's computer, not my own.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico thanks for the clarification. That wasn't quite clear in the question. See edit to option 3 which still shows how you can edit the functions, but now to insert a more general `on.exit` rather than assuming that you want the behaviour to happen at a `stop`

Comment: NB I also deleted what was option 2, since that did not seem so relevent now with this additional information. Option3 now becomes option 2

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying and answer but I'm not sure what you want, could you edit your functions to add an on.exit  ? :

```
mylistofstate<-list()
fn <- function() {
  x <-1
    on.exit(mylistofstate["x"]<<-x, add=TRUE)
    stop()
}
fn()
 > Error in fn() : 
mylistofstate
 > $x
 >[1] 1
```

Comment: hi, the goal is to access the object `x` but _not_ edit `fn()` in any way..  so i don't want to add `on.exit` to `fn()`

Answer (score 1):

This method allows access to the execution environment of `myfun` without requiring that it be rewritten:

```
checkX <- function () { print(get("x", envir=parent.frame())) }
checkFun <- function (f) {
  eval(parse(text=c("on.exit(checkX())", deparse(body(f)))))
}
```

You can make `checkX` do what you need, it can get full access to the function's execution context through the `parent.frame()` call.

```
myfun <- function(){ x <- 1 ; stop( "error here" ) }
checkFun(myfun)
```

To handle functions with arguments, you can wrap the old function with this:

```
wrapFun <- function (f) {
  eval(parse(text=c(deparse(args(f))[1], "{", "on.exit(checkX())", deparse(body(f)), "}")))
}
```

And call it with the arguments you want:

```
myfun2 <- function(y){ x <- y + 1 ; stop( "error here" ) }
wrapFun(myfun2)(3)
```

Comment: hi, i get `Error in eval(parse(text = c("on.exit(checkX())", deparse(body(f))))) : 
  error here
Error in print(x) : object 'x' not found` so it doesn't display the value of `x`?

Comment: My apologies, I mis-pasted stuff. Please try the newly edited answer.

Comment: thanks, that does work!  is there a way to get it working if the function has arguments?  `myfun2 <- function(y){ x <- y + 1 ; stop( "error here" ) }`  does not work

Comment: Check the latest edit and see if that'll work for you.